# android update record and requery

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update, cursor

Developing an application that displays data retrieved from it's database in the initial screen.  Users can edit the data via a separate edit screen.  Exiting the edit screen returns the user to the initial display screen, I requery the database but the data returned is the values prior to the edit.

I am using a db provider model and have tried:

- closing the cursor used in the initial database lookup
- using a separate cursor each time returning to the initial screen
- using a separate query to get the data displayed on the edit screen
- ensure that each cursor used is closed when work with that cursors data is complete

Database queries and relaunching the application shows the edited values so I am sure that the update is working.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)?

Comment: Not using a loader, just working on one record at a time.

Comment: At this point you need to figure out where your code is not doing what you expect it to. Verify that you are actually running a new query when you return to the initial screen, that this new query actually returns some data, that this triggers an update of the UI and binds new values to your views, that the new values are actually new values and not stale values (perhaps there's some kind of caching involved), etc. Somewhere in there something is not working as intended.

Comment: @T.Barrett try using `finish()` on the initial screen when you move to the edit screen OR if you're re querying the database in `onCreate()` remove it from there and put it else where like `onResume()`

Comment: I currently do the requery in my onResume so will try to add the finish step.

Comment: calling finish() did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the issue was related to misunderstanding states in the class used to support the editor function.  Thought the onStop() and onDestroy() would be called when exiting the edit screen and was calling the method to update the database in those methods.

Changed to use onBackPressed() instead and complete the update process before the updated values are displayed.